# Total probability theorem - an applicative example.

Tags: probability

A child, who has both parents suffering from allergies, has a risk of 60% of it in turn, but this probability is reduced to 40% if a single parent has allergies. surveys carried out at national level have shown that 25% of school-age children suffer from one or more allergic diseases and that these diseases have an incidence of 12.9% in adult women and 9.6% of adult men.

a) Determines the probability that a child has only one allergic parent;

b) Determines the probability that a child has both parents are allergic;

c) Determine the probability that a child chosen at random is not allergic and has a allergic mother and a not allergic father (reference solution: ~2%)

d) Determine the probability of choosing a child at random , and found to be allergic, both parents have allergies (reference solution: ~2,9%)

e) Determine the probability of choosing a child at random , and found to be allergic, has only one allergic parent (reference solution: ~32%)

I have successfully solved the questions A and B, as follows:

Question A: Notation: AN = Father Allergic / Mother Not Allergic; NA = Father Not Allergic / Mother Allergic; AA = Father Allergic / Mother Allergic; NN = Father Not Allergic / Mother Not Allergic

p(AN) + p(NA ) = 0.083616 + 0.116616 = 0.200232 = 20%

Question B: (same notations as in question A)

p(AA) = 9.6 / 100 * 12.9/ 100 = 0.012384 = 1.2384 %
p(AN) = 9.6 / 100 * 87.1 / 100 = 0.083616
p(NA) = 90.4 / 100 * 12.9 / 100 = 0.116616
p(NN) = 90.4 / 100 * 87.1 / 100 = 0.787384

How could I solve the points C, D and E, using Total Probability theorem?

Thank you very much for considering my request.

Comment: I would say the points A, B are correctly, if a child is selected "at random" (do not mention it in your query).

Comment: Thank you. Have you any idea to solve Question C, D and E?

Comment: How did you solve c) ?

Comment: I did not solve c, I have only accepted the answer to the unique user that helped me for D and E.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution for d) and e) with A="child is allergic":

d)  B="both parents have allergies "

$$ P(B \mid A )  =\frac{ P(B \cap A) }{ P(A)} = P(A\mid B ) \frac{P(B)}{P(A)} = 0.6 \cdot \frac{p(AA)}{0.25} $$

e)  B="only one parent is allergic"

$$ P(B \mid A )  =\frac{ P(B \cap A) }{ P(A)} = P(A\mid B ) \frac{P(B)}{P(A)} = 0.4 \cdot \frac{(p(AN)+p(NA))}{0.25} $$

This is my approach for c)

c)

$$ P(A^C \cap NA) = P(A^C \mid NA) P(NA) = (1 - P(A \mid NA)) P(NA)$$

but unfortunately it is only
$$ P(A \mid NA \cup AN)  $$
given.  I think some information is missing in order to solve c).